# How to copy paste images from / to OneNote web app from / to local PC?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Does OneNote web app support paste image from clipboard (with `ctrl+v`)?

I can manage to copy an image from web and directly paste into OneNote, but I cannot copy from my PC, and paste into OneNote.

So, I tried copying an image from web and paste into desktop Word, and paste the image from Word but failing to paste into OneNote web app.

Also, how can I copy an image from OneNote web app and paste into my desktop Word, or anywhere? It seems only paste a link to https://onenote.officeapps.live.com/o/GetImage.ashx?Fi=SD.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy into the web app you must use the insert picture command. To Copy outside of the app is only possible with text. It is referenced here.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/copy-and-paste-in-office-web-apps-HA101792391.aspx#_Toc286947876